# Drupal 6.x Ubercart 2.x Changing admin order email template

Tags: drupal, themes, customization, ubercart

I have some problem with modification admin template, normally it is located in path /sites/all/modules/ubercart/uc_order/templates but I am working on multisite-installation site and I don't have access there, I can only see three catalogs *modules*, *themes* and *files*. The problem is that in *modules* catalog are only those that I have install to custom my page (cant see ubercart).

Is there any way to customize this themes to add more information without changing directly file *uc_order-admin.tpl.php*.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you have access to template.php in your theme directory, you can point it to that template.

Comment: UberInvoice module solved my problem! You can find it on github under link: https://github.com/md-2/UberInvoice

Comment: Great! That's a good find!